# Comparing Strings using == vs Ordinal

Tags: c#, string-comparison

MS docs recommend using `Ordinal` for better Performance and for comparisons as your safe default for culture-agnostic string matching.
But curious to know how comparing using `==` differs in terms of performace and comparison.
using `==` seems a straight forward way. But I am sure it has its catches. Not sure what are those.

Comment: Well for one, `==` doesn't ignore case. Do you want to ignore case or not?

Comment: I dont want to ignore case

Comment: Then edit your question and use Ordinal. Apart from that i guess == is using Ordinal, so is basically syntactic sugar for it.

Comment: did it, but I  also wanna know the goto method of comparing strings in a more performant way. is it straight away using == or ordinal or ordinalIgnore case for case insensitives. trying to understand that

Comment: Unless you have a need for extremely high performance, worrying about performance at this level is a waste of time. Write the code in a way that your team considers to be the most readable. Also note that comparing strings and testing for equality are not the same thing.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Don't need to guess. [It's documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.op_equality?view=net-6.0): "The operator, in turn, calls the static Equals(String, String) method, which performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison."

Comment: Bottom line: always use `==` unless you have a reason not to (e.g., ignore case, invariant culture, specific culture, etc.).

Comment: Use the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.op_equality?view=net-6.0), Remarks section.  So case-insensitive and ordinal.